# Sed Command Escaping: Why the Inconsistencies with Single and Double Quotes?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm encountering an issue while using the `sed` command for regex substitution. Specifically, I'm having trouble with escaping characters within single and double quotes.

I've noticed that when I use the command:

```bash
echo "earth" | sed 's/\(ear\)$/\1md/g'
```

The substitution works as expected, transforming "earth" into "earmd".

However, when I attempt to use:

```bash
sh -c "echo "earth" | sed "s/\(ear\)th$/\1md/g""
```

or

```bash
sh -c 'echo "earth" | sed 's/\(ear\)th$/\1md/g''
```

I encounter the error:

```bash
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Interestingly, if I use:

```bash
sh -c 'echo "earth" | sed "s/\(ear\)th$/\1md/g"'
```

or

```bash
sh -c "echo "earth" | sed 's/\(ear\)th$/\1md/g'"
```

The substitution works as expected, transforming "earth" into "earmd".

I understand that double quotes `""` can handle some special escape characters, while single quotes `''` ignore all special handling. However, I'm unclear on how this mechanism leads to the observed behavior. Any insights into this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: In your second snippet, the first double-quote is closed before the word "earth".  In your third snippet, the first single-quote is closed just after the word `sed`.  Quotes don't nest like that.

Comment: Take a close look at the syntax highlight here for your code snippets. It really tells much.

Comment: You have a weird quoting in the error case. First case: The double quote opens just in front of `echo` and closed again in front of `earth`.  Then it opens again after `earth`, making your pipe character part of the quoted string. The second error is similar, just with single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case

```
sh -c "echo "earth" | sed "s/\(ear\)th$/\1md/g""
```

It is reporting error because you are attempting double quotes inside a string enclosed by double quotes without escaping the character, causing bash to think the command string to be just `echo` . If the outter most quote is double-quote, to escape the nested double quote character, you just need to add backslash behind that quote

```
sh -c "echo \"earth\" | sed \"s/\(ear\)th$/\1md/g\""
```

However, if the outter most quote is single-quote, in this case, you can't escape the nested single quote character with backslash character like with double quotes. You can alternate the use between double and single like in your fourth example

```
sh -c 'echo "earth" | sed "s/\(ear\)th$/\1md/g"'
```

It works because the single quote is enclosing the string so you can use double quotes freely inside the single quote without needing escape characters.

For the case

```
sh -c "echo "earth" | sed 's/\(ear\)th$/\1md/g'"
```

It works because `sh` seems to consider three separated strings `"echo "`, `earth`, and `" | sed 's/\(ear\)th$/\1md/g'"` into a single string

```
echo "earth" | sed 's/\(ear\)th$/\1md/g'
```

because there are no spaces between them

Similar behavior can be observed in below command

```
sh -c "echo "earth" && echo 'water'"
```

This will output

```
earth
water
```

Whereas, if I add a space between `earth` and the third double quotes

```
sh -c "echo "earth " && echo 'water'"
```

It will only output

```
earth
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing has to do with **how quotes are handled in bash** in general (and many programming languages) and **isn't specifically a sed issue**.

I'll use your first example where you got the error as a reference:

```
sh -c "echo "earth" | sed "s/\(ear\)th$/\1md/g""
```

The correct way to do what you are attempting above is this:

```
sh -c "echo 'earth' | sed 's/\(ear\)th$/\1md/g'"
```

Explanation:

The issue you are running in to is the first open of a double quote at `sh -c "echo` is closed by the the double quote at `"earth`. Then, a new quoted segment is opened by the double quote at `earth"` and is closed by the double quote at `sed "s`. This leaves the text `s/\(ear\)th$/\1md/g` unquoted and finally, you have an open double quote and close double quote to end the line, `1md/g""`. In the alternative that I have provided, the double quote opens at `sh -c "echo` and closes at `1md/g'"`. Inside, `'earth'` is quoted with single quotes and `'s/\(ear\)th$/\1md/g'` is closed by its single quotes. With using the double quotes on the outside and single quotes for strings inside, you avoid the unintentional open/closing of double quotes that you were running in to.

Acknowledgement: Tim Roberts's comment, which was posted before my answer, about the nesting is correct.